Transaction not found in getSignaturesForAddress() returned array
getSignaturesForAddress misses one particular transaction of slot 304499001, for address Fch1oixTPri8zxBnmdCEADoJW2toyFHxqDZacQkwdvSP, transaction signature is pMsjGQE7vRKqBBQHvP8o5SxwDieDwgwscWG5eHoECbJy4kJ7XnGSpyCXP8UkHVvfQtT8313bne9TBcWgXm7VnVM
    blockTime: 1732953798,
    confirmationStatus: 'finalized',
    err: null,
    memo: null,
    signature: '5vHtdoE7erqw2fSWjkXQfkVLirwmbuZZdtLbrxZTooManteLdULW8TicNkDRLLGFPyQpmnNnnq7z5uaKXiUnzvti',    
    slot: 304499176
  },
// must be here between those two
  {
    blockTime: 1732953665,
    confirmationStatus: 'finalized',
    err: null,
    memo: null,
    signature: 'SMbtHjcwu4Cbkg2U6WU2Zk8UeRPjj6ttWApVPcNe86J6GVnmGRMVQzFPaxbwa63rszxz1igBfqe3VopcXWWUUqp',     
    slot: 304498847
  },

What could be wrong? Is that a bug or something else?

It looks like that transaction isn't directly using the Fch1oixTPri8zxBnmdCEADoJW2toyFHxqDZacQkwdvSP account, so it won't show up in the getSignaturesForAddress. The transaction is only outputting that pubkey as event data.
